# Is 'name after' used before persons?

Tags: prepositions

I have known that 'name after' is used after persons. Look at this sentence:

> The village is **named after** the donor's surname.

Is this usage is correct, if not what can be replaced in the place of 'after'?

Comment: Unlike "named after", "name after" seems like it would be rare, and shouldn't be used in that sort of context. ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

Not just people. You can name something after somebody or even something else. It's *name sb/sth after sb/sth*. Think of Lake Mead.

> The lake was named after Elwood Mead who was a commissioner of the U.S.

Also they use *name sb/sth for sb/sth*; it's more common in American English though, as in

> She told us about his ​brother, Apollo, ​born in 1969 and ​named for the US ​astronauts' ​mission to the ​moon.

So to answer your question, I'd say, *"yes you can name a village after a person."*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the usage is perfectly correct. It is used about buildings, streets, even villages, but it is most often used about babies:

> She's named after her grandmother

"Named for" is also used, mainly in the US. [This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043639/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/he-or-she-versus-they) has some information about the differences in usage.